# Why i am getting "< was expected at this time error" while calling the windows command "echo "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>" > tmp.xml"

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file, utf-8

I am trying to add the line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` to `tmp.xml` using the following Windows command:

```
echo <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> > tmp.xml
```

I am getting an error:

```
>was expected at this time
```

I tried with double quotes:

```
echo "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>" > tmp.xml
```

This writes the line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` in the file, but within double quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try using `^` as an escape character before reserved characters such as `<` and `>`.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\topdog>echo ^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?^> > tmp.xml

C:\Users\topdog>type tmp.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

C:\Users\topdog>
```

Comment: To answer an obvious follow-up question (with the obvious answer :)), if you want to do something like echo an actual ^ character then put two of them together like so: `echo Ten to the power of two = 10^^2` results in this being displayed: `Ten to the power of two = 10^2`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest quotes like that. `"one "two" three"` contains the unquoted string `two` bracketed by two quoted strings, none of which contain actual literal `"` characters.

Comment: Since XML is quote indifferent, just use single quotes everywhere inside the outer double.